# In C#, is it a considerable way to rewrite all singly referenced class to struct?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that has a lot of members.

```
public class MyClass{
    public int ModuleA_Value00;
    public int ModuleA_Value01;
    public void ModuleAMethod0(){}
    public int ModuleB_Value00;
    public int ModuleB_Value01;
    public int ModuleC_Value00;
    public int ModuleC_Value01;
//Just illustration, in fact there should be much more.
}
```

In order to make the code to be more readable, I break the class members down into several smaller classes that don't care about how other types works.

```
public class MyClass{
    public ModuleA ModuleA;
    public ModuleB ModuleB;
    public ModuleC ModuleC;
}
public class ModuleA{
    public int Value00;
    public int Value01;
    public void Method0(){};
}
public class ModuleB{
    public int Value00;
    public int Value01;
}
public class ModuleC{
    public int Value00;
    public int Value01;
}
```

Then I start doubting to change `ModuleA`,`ModuleB`, and `ModuleC` from class to struct. This is seriously violating the doctrine regulating such that:

1. A struct should not be mutable
2. A struct should be as small as possible

However I think this is acceptable for these reasons:

1. Those instance are only, for each of them, going to be referenced by a single object therefore not necessary to be reference type and being value type could improve performance by less GC effort.
2. They don't need to be inherited.
3. They are unlikely to be boxed.

Does my idea make sense?

Comment: It seems you want records not structs (the copy on use effects from structs means you're making future maintenance harder when someone updates that code without realising these are mutable structs).

Comment: Note that your class members will have to be fields, rather than properties, otherwise you won't be able to set any of the structs' members.

Comment: My first question when it comes to performance: Do you have problems with your performance? Don't over optimize in advance when there are no problems.

Comment: @Richard Records are classes in fact, so there won't be much benefit in "...could improve performance by less GC effort"

Comment: Note that if your class members are properties, rather than fields, then accessing one requires a copy of the struct.

Comment: If the only reason why you'd like to change a class into a mutable structure is to save on GC, keeping it a class is often a safer choice. Usually, you have plenty of opportunities to improve performance before GC becomes your bottleneck.

Comment: @canton7 structs can be passed by ref

Answer (score 3):

> Does my idea make sense?

No.

There is zero benefit to using a struct over a class, and many drawbacks, unless you **absolutely** need the characteristics of a struct. Performance is only a concern if you're going to be allocating thousands of these types.

As with all things, don't optimize until or unless you need to, and especially don't micro-optimize. Choosing struct over class is definitely a micro-optimization.

Comment: Sometimes GC is even faster, especially when it can run delayed when the app is idling anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great idea, rather you can use the concept of `Partial Classes` from c#. This will allow you to maintain single class but segregated in different files and easy for readability.

Partial classes have nothing to do with object inheritance. Partial classes are just a way of splitting the source code that defines a class into separate files

You can create these classes in different files :

e.g.
MyClass.cs

```
public partial class MyClass{
    public int ModuleA_Value00;
    public int ModuleA_Value01;
    
}
```

MyClass1.cs

```
public partial class MyClass{   
    public void ModuleAMethod0(){}
    public int ModuleB_Value00;
    
}
```

MyClass2.cs

```
public partial class MyClass{
    public int ModuleB_Value01;
    public int ModuleC_Value00;
    public int ModuleC_Value01;
}
```

**There are some points that you should be when you are developing a partial class in your application.**

- You need to use partial keyword in each part of partial class.
- The name of each part of partial class should be the same but source file name for each - part of partial class can be different.
- All parts of a partial class should be in the same namespace.
- Each part of a partial class should be in the same assembly or DLL, in other words you can't create a partial class in source files of a different class library project.
- Each part of a partial class has the same accessibility.
- If you inherit a class or interface on a partial class then it is inherited on all parts of a partial class.
- If a part of a partial class is sealed then the entire class will be sealed.
- If a part of partial class is abstract then the entire class will be an abstract class.

[Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)